# video streaming over bluetooth, Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, streaming

I am developing an application connecting a PC with Android based device over bluetooth, I have established the connection and implemented most of my project ideas.

However, I would like to add streaming functionality from the PC to the device, I don't have any code yet as I am still in the planning stage! So I would like to ask for any helpful resources or tutorials? anything helpful as a first step?

I have implemented the PC side where I basically get the stream frames in the form of byte array, to be sent to the Android side...

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way we could find was to actually implement a simple protocol for the transfer.
We compressed the individual frames, divided them into packets at the PC side, added a header for each packet, and a header packet for the entire frame, containing the total length of the frame and number of packets.

At the android side, we ran two nested loops, one for the frames of the stream, and one for the packets of individual packets. We used the data from the first packet of the frame to figure out the length of the loop and when to break, after we get the total frame size (verified by the first packet) we sent the total bytearray into a function converting the array into jpg immage, and used a canvas to continuesly showing the frames...

we got about two frames per second, which was good enough for bluetooth...

Comment: um i am tryin to do the same here. problem is in my receiver program if i have a while(true) loop to keep reading from the stream nothing is then shown to the screen and if not it shows the first taken shot what am i doing wrong. Please help me

Comment: I kinda do the same as u said up there and i can post my code in another question just reply to me.

Comment: @NZal Please share with us example link or code, Please :(

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to stream video is using the VDP (Video Distribution Profile), but there isn't much existing support for doing that on Android.  You can write your own app using SPP (serial port profile), which will give you a raw data pipe.  You can find plenty of SPP examples on google.

Comment: Any examples you know of? I have implemented the SPP for my project, my problem is how to get the array of bytes and of each frame and merge it into a video stream in real time !